# How to compare current time with predetermined time

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a prayer time application. In my application, I calculate upcoming prayer remaining time(by comparing current time) and my countdown timer starts.

I don't know how to calculate remaining time for next prayer time? Please help.

The result that i got : "Fajr : 5000"

I want the result like this :

Example : Fajr time is 04:00:00 and system time is 03:50:00, and the result is "Fajr : - 00:10:00"

Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getValueShubuh = jamShubuh.getText().toString().trim();

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            long timeDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            SimpleDateFormat prayerTimes = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
                            String prayerTime = prayerTimes.format(timeDate);

                            countdownPrayerTime(prayerTime);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}

private void countdownPrayerTime(String prayerTime) {
    String shubuhTime = getValueShubuh.replace(":", "") + "00";
    String dzuhurTime = getValueDzuhur.replace(":", "") + "00";
    String asharTime = getValueAshar.replace(":", "") + "00";
    String maghribTime = getValueMaghrib.replace(":", "") + "00";
    String isyaTime = getValueIsya.replace(":", "") + "00";

    int countDown = Integer.parseInt(prayerTime) - Integer.parseInt(shubuhTime);

    shalatCountdown.setText(("Fajr : " + countDown).replace("-", ""));
}
```

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis();` is outdated. And you pass time as a string?? I'd suggest to always use new classes from `java.time` package and using an `Instant now = Instant.now();` and later compare it to another instant. https://www.baeldung.com/current-date-time-and-timestamp-in-java-8

Comment: You tell us your desired result, but what is your current result? What have you tried to solve your problem and why does this not work?

Comment: @parsecer if i use LocalTime it requires minimal API too high

Comment: @topher217 i have editted my question, thanks

Comment: Ok, so you tell us what you get, but not what your have tried to solve the problem. Why do you think you are getting this current result of 5000? (i.e. if you don't understand your own code well enough to answer this, then it will be very difficult for others to understand it, much less help to answer it).

Comment: @Mr.Robot wdym minimal API? `LocalTime` is something like a date of birth - you know someone is born on say 4 October 1983 at 6pm, but that's it. You can't tell the particular moment of that person being born and if someone were to ask you if that person was born before or after a TV show that aired at 9pm UTC-3 4 October, you wouldn't be able to tell, because `LocalTime` stores no information about timezone.

Comment: `Instant` on the other hand, is very simple and very precise - it counts the number of nanoseconds that has passed since 1 Jan 1970. Then you could easily compare two instance, get the number of minutes/hours/days b/w them and only perform a certain action when two instances are a particular number of minutes apart etc